# On-Site real-time widget using Node/Socket.io + PHP

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, node.js, socket.io

Gurus of SO

I am experimenting with a tiny widget that you can put on any site using a single line of JavaScript code, similar to the many chatting apps available today. My question is which is the best way to do this - iFrame or not? Also, what are the security measures to think of when introducing your code on third party sites?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On some widgets i've used iframes because it offers me more flexibility and i didn't need to inject some javascript libraries into client's DOM, which could harm the entire page. For auto-resizing based on content i've used window.postMessage.

Comment: You have any experience in doing this with a Node/Socket backend?